# Set connection according to user data logged

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I created a second connection in my config/database.php and will also create a third connection, wanted to know how can I do to switch between these connections according to the logged in user.

**config/database.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'database2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => ('localhost'),
            'port' => ('3306'),
            'database' => ('database2'),
            'username' => ('root'),
            'password' => (''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

I know I can choose my modem connection in that way, but how do you that name "**database2**" is pulled from the logged in user instead of being placed the name directly there?

```
class Empresa extends Model
{
    protected $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->connection = 'database2';
    }
}
```

I tried to put it that way, but it did not work.

```
return $this->connection = Auth::user()->database;
```

He gave this error.

> ErrorException in Empresa.php line 16:
>
> Trying to get property of non-object